# How to remove lines which contain asterisk by using sed command

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, text-processing

I have a file which contain following lines.

```
**;**;**;
*(Eng_Sen:This is an apple)*;*(WordID:1 2 3 4)*;*(message:)*;
**;**;**
```

I want to delete all the lines which contain following patterns using Sed command.

```
**;**;**;
**;**;**
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Why `sed` in particular? Considering the particular characters involved, it would be hard to read in those patterns from a file or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
sed '/\*\*;\*\*;\*\*;\?/d' file
```

- `\*\*;\*\*;\*\*;\?`: matches a `**;**;**` string optionally followed by a `;` character;
- `d`: deletes the line.

To edit the file in place:

```bsh
sed -i '/\*\*;\*\*;\*\*;\?/d' file
```

```bsh
% cat file                                          :(
**;**;**;
*(Eng_Sen:This is an apple)*;*(WordID:1 2 3 4)*;*(message:)*;
**;**;**
% sed '/\*\*;\*\*;\*\*;\?/d' file
*(Eng_Sen:This is an apple)*;*(WordID:1 2 3 4)*;*(message:)*;
%
```

Answer (score 1):

More generically, to remove any line that only contains semicolons and asterisks:

```
sed '/^[*;]\+$/d'
```

Although you don't need to restrict yourself to sed:

```
grep -Ev '^[*;]+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

kos's answer already does the job. My answer only improves the regex somewhat.

By using the grouping pattern `\( \)` and the escaped `.\+` we can tell it to match the whole group  `**;` and whatever else is followed. In this example I am using

```
$  sed -e "s|\(\*\*;\).\+|TEST|g"  stars.txt                            
TEST
*(Eng_Sen:This is an apple)TEST
TEST
TEST
*(Eng_Sen:This is an apple)TEST
TEST
```

Note that GNU `sed` version can take any character as separator in the substitution command, not just `/`. Here I was using vertical bar.

In the example above ,I've taken the liberty to increase the OP's example from 3 to 6 lines.

```
$ cat stars.txt                                                
**;**;**;
*(Eng_Sen:This is an apple)*;*(WordID:1 2 3 4)*;*(message:)*;
**;**;**
**;**;**;
*(Eng_Sen:This is an apple)*;*(WordID:1 2 3 4)*;*(message:)*;
**;**;**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'g/\*\*/d' -cx file
```

1. `g` global search
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close